# accessing image from public_html not possible

Tags: hosting, cpanel, public-html

I am using Cyberhost.in to host a JSF application. The problem that I am facing is that whenever I am trying to access image files from `public_html` folder I am getting a `404 error`. I have kept my war file in `webapps` folder. I am using c-panel, the thing is that I want to take backup of files for my website so I have kept them in `public_html` folder. Initially I was saving the files under `webapps/[WAR FILE NAME]` but when ever I was trying to overwrite `webapps/[WAR FILE NAME]` I was getting `permission denied error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upload image files on their location that you have mentioned in your code, otherwise you should change the location in website code of the same.

Also check permissions/ownership of files